# Locally compactness of euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis

A metric space $X$ is locally compact  if every point of $X$ has a compact neighborhood. How can I show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact? MY thoughts: Pick arbitrary $x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can find an $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) = \{ y : ||x-y|| \leq r \} $, which is closed and bounded, hence compact. Therefore, euclidean space is locally compact... Is this correct? or Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an easy consequences of the fact that a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by the balls and the Heine-Borel Theorem which is valid here.

for further topics you can see [this page](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/)